# Embedded C- UTF8 to MARC8

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm using STM32 as my microprocessor,i'm trying to access an array containing my arabic font for the LCD
My issue is that the characters are sorted by MARC8, but the parsing occurs using UTF8

Example

```
   unsigned char * C = "ب";
```

HEX values are D8A8 While it should be C8 only.

Any solution ?

Comment: I suspect `ب` is some UTF-8 character. If you want `C8`, then store C8: `const unsigned char * C = "\xC8";`

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible approaches.

**Conversion before runtime**

Use (write) an external program to transform the texts into the target encoding. It should output a list of `#define` lines, or an `enum` definition and an array of bytes in C syntax, that can be used like a header in `#include`. For example,

```
#define SOME_TEXT "\xE2\x96\x94\x85\x40\xA3\x85\xA7\xA3" /* this is actually EBCDIC */
```

then use these in the program

```
const char *sometext = SOME_TEXT;
```

This is advantageous on an embedded platform with limited speed and memory, because the conversion tables and routines are not stored on the target.

The disadvantage is that text supplied by other systems electronically (over the network or on a memory card) must still somehow be converted before use.

**Conversion in runtime**

You can of course use a simple conversion function that takes takes an unicode string, and transforms it character by character to some other encoding, using a mapping table like

```
struct ucs_to_marc8 {
    unsigned char code1, code2;
    unsigned char marc8;
};
const struct ucs_to_marc8 ucs_to_marc8_table[] = {
    { 0xD8, 0xA7, 0xC7 }, // aleph
    { 0xD8, 0xA8, 0xC8 }, // beh
    /* etc */
    { 0, 0, 0 } };
```